# I want to send Ascii bytes with Embarcadero XE Delphi?

Tags: c#, sockets, delphi

I want to convert my C# code to Delphi.

I am trying to send messages to a bank card terminal (speed point). Please assist. I have one of this MagIC3 devices. When I send messages over socket using C# I get my messages to the device successfully. On the other hand with Delphi its just quiet.

Here's is my C# Code:

```
    public void CardRead
    {
        try
        {
            string length;
            String szData = "E0940|" + sessionID + "|00|" + "Please Swip Card|";
            length = szData.Length.ToString();
            while (length.Length < 6)
            {
                length = "0" + length;
            }
            szData = length + szData;
            byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(szData);
            socClient.Send(byData);
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
        }
    }
```

Problem is my Delphi code:

```
procedure TForm1.CardRead; 
var
 wInt                       :Integer;
 wLength, szData            :String;
 wData                      :TBytes;
begin

 try

  szData := 'E0940|' + sessionID + '|00|' + 'Please Swipe Card|';
  wLength := IntToStr(Length(szData));
  While (Length(wLength) < 6) do
  begin
   wLength := '0' + wLength;
  end;
  szData := wLength + szData;
  wData := TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(szData);

  socClient.IOHandler.WriteBufferOpen;

  for wInt := 0 to Length(wData) do
  begin
   socClient.Socket.WriteLn;
  end;

  socClient.Socket.WriteLn;
  socClient.Socket.WriteBufferClose;

 except
  socClient.Socket.WriteBufferCancel;
  raise;
 end;

end;
```

Comment: You are sending N+1 end of lines where N is the length of the data. Did you mean to do that? Why would you call Writeln when you want to send binary data?

Comment: Maybe I've missed something but the c# code sends a block of binary data and the Delphi code appears to send a pile of empty new lines? Where do you pass `wData` to the socket for it to send it? I would expect something like `socClient.Socket.Write(wData);`

Comment: The Delphi code does nothing close to what the C# code does. The C# code sends a single stream of bytes (using `soSocket.Send`), while you're Delphi code sends a CR/LF terminated line for each byte of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Indy sockets you need to use the `Write` procedure instead of the `Writeln`( it only writes a new line). So something like this

```
soClient.Socket.Write(wData)
```

should do the trick. Note that you are opening the buffer of the `IOHandler` and then using the socket instead. I suppose you need to open the socket buffer. And don't forget to `WriteBufferFlush`  the socket so no data stays in the buffer.